# popupmenu android 5.1.1 - popupmenu touches the edge of screen

Tags: android, popupmenu, android-5.1.1-lollipop

When I open `popupmenu` from `listview` item it touches the edge of screen - there is no margin between popupmenu and edge of screen.

I am using `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu` and it works fine on android 4.4.2. Popupmenu is anchored to button in listview item.

Is it the issue of android 5.1.1 ? Anybody knows how to solve it?